# Get Google Charts Table's current page

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to paginate a table and want to save the current page before redrawing so I will be able to set it as a startPage later on.

How can i access the table's current page?

Comment: what do you mean with "save the current page" ? like export it to cvs file or something?

Comment: No, just to be able to save the table's state and set it as the start page on load later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone,

I ended up using the Query Language in combination of a custom function on Page events.

The query enabled me to set an offset to the table and it works fine.

Here's a reference to the Query Language:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Offset

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#tablequerywrapper

And that's how you run a custom function on Google Charts events:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that google API does not support this natively?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I figured out how to do what you're wanting:

```
var currentPage = 0;  //at the beginning of your code, like a chartWrapper

//in your ready event:
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'page', function(e) { returnTablePage(e) });

//as a separate function:
function returnTablePage(e) { currentPage = e.page; }
```

I put it in a separate function because I need to do several things...